# How to set field value of form field in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom, adminform

I am trying to set the value of Field in form using below code:

```
         $fieldset->addField(
        'hideGoogle',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'hideGoogle',
            'label' => __('Hide Google'),
            'values' => '1', 
        ]
    );
```

But its' not setting the value. I am also tried 'value' instead of 'values' but not working. Can anyone please tell me how can I set the field value in Magento 2 admin form?

Answer (score 6):

You have to add below code in form file

**app\code\Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\ModuleName\Edit\Form.php**

```
    $model->setData('test', 'female');
```

Example of form file:

```
<?php
namespace Mystore\Slider\Block\Adminhtml\Slider\Edit;

/**
 * Adminhtml blog post edit form
 */
class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
     */
    protected $_systemStore;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Init form
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('mystore_slider_form');
        $this->setTitle(__('Slider Information'));
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        /** @var \Ashsmith\Blog\Model\Post $model */
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('mystore_slider');

        if ($model->getId()) {
            $model->setData('test', 'female');
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => ['id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]
        );

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('mystore_slider_');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'base_fieldset',
            ['legend' => __('General Information'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
        );

        if ($model->getSliderId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('slider_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'slider_id']);
        }

        $fieldset->addField(
            'slider_title',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'slider_title', 'label' => __('Slider Title'), 'title' => __('Slider Title'), 'required' => true]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'url',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'url',
                'label' => __('Slider URL'),
                'title' => __('Slider URL'),
                'required' => true,
                'class' => 'validate-xml-identifier'
            ]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'image',
            'image',
            [
                'name' => 'image',
                'label' => __('Slider Image'),
                'title' => __('Slider Image'),
                'required' => true
            ]
        );


        $fieldset->addField(
            'test', 
            'radios',
            [
                'label' => __('test'),
                'title' => __('test'),
                'name' => 'test',
                'required' => true, 
                'values' => array(
                        array('value'=>'male','label'=>'Male'),
                        array('value'=>'female','label'=>'Female'),
                   )
            ]
        );

        /**
         * Check is single store mode
         */
        if (!$this->_storeManager->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $field = $fieldset->addField(
                'store_id',
                'multiselect',
                [
                    'name' => 'stores[]',
                    'label' => __('Store View'),
                    'title' => __('Store View'),
                    'required' => true,
                    'values' => $this->_systemStore->getStoreValuesForForm(false, true)
                ]
            );
            $renderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher\Form\Renderer\Fieldset\Element'
            );
            $field->setRenderer($renderer);
        } else {
            $fieldset->addField(
                'store_id',
                'hidden',
                ['name' => 'stores[]', 'value' => $this->_storeManager->getStore(true)->getId()]
            );
            $model->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore(true)->getId());
        }

        $fieldset->addField(
            'is_active',
            'select',
            [
                'label' => __('Status'),
                'title' => __('Status'),
                'name' => 'is_active',
                'required' => true,
                'options' => ['1' => __('Enabled'), '0' => __('Disabled')]
            ]
        );        

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: in block form , I have input field type="text" and i am trying to set some random value to that but it is not setting. below is code . Please help me :$fieldset->addField(
                'category_code', 'text',['name' => 'category_code1', 
                      'value'=> $this->vendorAutoCode(),
                    'label' => __('Category Code'), 'title' => __('Category Code'), 'required' => true]
        );     public function vendorAutoCode(){
      return  str_pad(rand(0,9999), 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }

Answer (score 4):

you can set values of **form**  with below code. add this code after the fields are defined. **Tested**...

```
$data=array('hideGoogle'=>1);    
$form->setValues($data);
```

before this code

```
$this->setForm($form);
```

Comment: perfect working

Comment: Thanks a lot! +1

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
$field = $fieldset
  ->addField(
        'hideGoogle',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'hideGoogle',
            'label' => __('Hide Google')
        ]
    );
$field->setValue('myvalue');
```

or:

```
$fieldset
  ->addField(
        'hideGoogle',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'hideGoogle',
            'label' => __('Hide Google'),
            'value' => 'myvalue'
        ]
    );
```

However, if you're overwriting the data later in the execution of your custom code, this won't work of course.

Comment: thanks @Milan simek its working perfect for me thanks a lot