# How to set default text field value in form Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, adminform

**I want to set field value of form field in Magento 2.**

**Actual Result**
[image]

**Expected Result**

[image]

I have added required code here which are available in my **Form.php**

```
<?php
namespace Magenest\Membership\Block\Adminhtml\Gift\Edit;

class Form extends FormGeneric
{
    protected $_status;
    protected $_systemStore;
    protected $_wysiwygConfig;
    protected $productGift;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        DataObject $objectConverter,
        SystemStore $systemStore,
        Config $wysiwygConfig,
        ProductGift $productGift,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_systemStore           = $systemStore;
        $this->_groupRepository       = $groupRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->_objectConverter       = $objectConverter;
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        $this->productGift = $productGift;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('membership_gift_edit');
        $data  = $model->getData();
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('page_');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Gift')." ".$model->getId()]);

        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField(
                'id',
                'hidden',
                ['name' => 'id']
            );
        }


            $fieldset->addField(
                'customer_id',
                'text',
                [
                    'label'    => __('Customer Id'),
                    'title'    => __('Customer Id'),
                    'name'     => 'customer_id',
                    'required' => true,
                ]
            );


        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $form->setAction($this->getUrl('membership/gift/save'));
        $form->setMethod('post');
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $form->setId('edit_form');
        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

}
```

I have tried as below but didn't get result.

**Try 1:**

```
            $fieldset->addField(
                'customer_id',
                'text',
                [
                    'label'    => __('Customer Id'),
                    'title'    => __('Customer Id'),
                    'name'     => 'customer_id',
                    'required' => true,
                ]
            );
$fieldset->setValue('myvalue');
```

**Try 2:**

```
            $fieldset->addField(
                'customer_id',
                'text',
                [
                    'label'    => __('Customer Id'),
                    'title'    => __('Customer Id'),
                    'name'     => 'customer_id',
                    'value' => 'test',

                ]
            );
```

I also refer below link but still facing an issue.
[How to set field value of form field in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146143/how-to-set-field-value-of-form-field-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'customer_id',
    'text',
    [
        'label'    => __('Customer Id'),
        'title'    => __('Customer Id'),
        'name'     => 'customer_id',
        'required' => true,
    ]
);

$model->setData('customer_id', '10');
```

**Second way:**

You can achieve this using following way also.

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'customer_id',
    'text',
    [
        'label'    => __('Customer Id'),
        'title'    => __('Customer Id'),
        'name'     => 'customer_id',
        'required' => true,
        'value' => '10',
    ]
);

...
...

    if ($model->getId()) {
        $form->setValues($model->getData());
    }
    $this->setForm($form);
```

Answer (score 3):

`setValues()` function is overriding the **'value'** that you have set for the field.
This line of code which would reset the form values:

```
$form->setValues($model->getData());
```

**Solution:**

Set model data before `setValues()` function as below:

```
if (!$model->getId()) {
    $model->setData('customer_id', '19');
}
$form->setValues($model->getData());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below code on same file it will sure work.

```
$model->setData('customer_id', "20");
 $form->setValues($model->getData());
```

I did use below code and its work fine for me

[image]

```
$model->setData('title', "yourValue");
  $form->setValues($model->getData());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below solution as well.

```
<?php
namespace Magenest\Membership\Block\Adminhtml\Gift\Edit;

class Form extends FormGeneric
{
    protected $_status;
    protected $_systemStore;
    protected $_wysiwygConfig;
    protected $productGift;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        DataObject $objectConverter,
        SystemStore $systemStore,
        Config $wysiwygConfig,
        ProductGift $productGift,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_systemStore           = $systemStore;
        $this->_groupRepository       = $groupRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->_objectConverter       = $objectConverter;
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        $this->productGift = $productGift;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('membership_gift_edit');
        $data  = $model->getData();
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('page_');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Gift')." ".$model->getId()]);

        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField(
                'id',
                'hidden',
                ['name' => 'id']
            );
        }


            $fieldset->addField(
                'customer_id',
                'text',
                [
                    'label'    => __('Customer Id'),
                    'title'    => __('Customer Id'),
                    'name'     => 'customer_id',
                    'required' => true,
                    'value' => '19'
                ]
            );


        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $form->setAction($this->getUrl('membership/gift/save'));
        $form->setMethod('post');
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $form->setId('edit_form');
        $_data = $model->getData();
        if ($model->getId()) {
            $form->setValues($_data);
        }
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what did you do to show the value? Because he has already tried your solution with `'value' => 'test' but it didn't work for him. Is there anything else you did?

Comment: Did you check the whole code? I have also put condition just before setForm. Don't comment without checking the whole code.

Comment: Yes I saw that but he already did it. He tried with `$form->setValues($model->getData());` and you just took the `$model->getData();` in variable and then set it.

Comment: I just want to learn that's why I am asking you.

Comment: Okay I got it. You are seting the data only if the model has id. otherwise you are not seting the data.

Comment: Am I right? Is this your logic?

Comment: @Dinesh No problem. Condition is for if form is for edit then it will set the model data otherwise(new) it will set the value you have mentioned as default in your form.

Comment: I am setting any values if form is new, it capture the value which is mentioned in the form field as deault(value) and if its edit then it sets data from model according to the conditions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82821/discussion-between-dinesh-yadav-and-sukumar-gorai).

Comment: Yes, It works.
+1 from my side :)