# How to set hidden field with value in Admin html - Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, adminform, magento2.2.8

I have added a field as per Magento standard structure, hidden field appeared but value is not showing.

```
$fieldset->addField('entity_type_id', 'hidden', 
    array(
      'name'               => 'entity_type_id',
      'value'              => 11
    ));
```

> NOTE : I have tried 'value' instead of 'values' but not working

Can anyone suggest how can I set the **field value** in Magento 2 admin form.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->setForm($form);
```

> custom field with field value

```
$data=array('entity_type_id'=>11);   
$form->setValues($data);
```

NOTE : I got reference from **[this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/146144/63138)** answer and it is working perfectly fine for me for hidden field as well for text field.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This :-**

> **Reference :-** vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Status/NewStatus/Form.php
>
> **Line no. 40**

```
$fieldset->addField('entity_type_id', 'hidden', 
   [
      'name' => 'entity_type_id',
      'value' => 11
   ]);
```

Comment: Hi @RkRathod it's not working. Value is not displaying in inspect element.

Comment: if I add value using inspect element, even tho it is not showing in text field :D

Comment: @AdityaShah have you got solution?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/288169/63138